# Find out if the number of selected items > 1 in a multiple select box using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, html-select

Is there a way I can find out if there are more than one items selected in a multiple select box?

I know it can be done in a linear fashion by going through each option individually, but I would like to avoid that because I am just going to enable or disable a UI component based on the number of items selected.

As this operation does not really require the values nor text value of the selected items, I am looking for a simple way like using pluck or something similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 59% over 87 questions. Remember to mark your questions as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you can use the descriptor;

```
$('.select-box:selected')
```

to return a list of all the selected items in a multiple select box. You can then use .size() to tell you how many there are.

```
if ( $('.select-box:selected').size() > 1 ) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `$('.select-box:selected').length` will give you number of options selected.

Comment: Sorry I was editing to include `.size()`. `.length` would work too.

Comment: Change the `$` to [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) and it works for Prototype too.

Comment: At all times I am getting the select size as zero even if there are a lot of items selected. I think when it is a multiselect select box there is no "selected" at all??

Comment: It is actually $$('.select-box option:selected').size() > 1 where .select-box is the css class